# The determinant of adjugate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have the following proof that I would like to be walked through because I'm not intuitively seeing what to do:

If $A$ is $n\times n$, prove $\det\left(\operatorname{adj}(A)\right) = \det(A)^{n-1}$.

I know the property of $A\operatorname{adj}(A) = \det(A)I$ is important but I don't know how to apply it to get an answer. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: All you need to use is that important property, and $\det(XY)=\det X\det Y$, and the formula for $\det cX$ when $c$ is a constant (and you need to know $\det I$). Try it!

Comment: @GerryMyerson to lay some basic ground level knowledge, det _I_ = 1, det _cX_ = c^n(det _X_), correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I hope I understand it now intuitively: since the minor of A is used in the calculation of the cofactor of A there will be 1 less row, hence n-1. What I still don't understand is how to use the various theorems established above to prove this relationship.

Comment: Take determinants on both sides of your $A({\rm adj}A)=\det(A)(I)$ formula.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what I end up with is det(_A_)det(adj _A_)) = det(det(_A_)). Does the right side of that equation equal (det(_A_))^n? Shouldn't a determinate of 1x1 matrix equal whatever the entry is in that matrix? At this point I'm stuck.

Comment: Remember that $\det A$ is just a number, and $\det(cX)=c^n\det X$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson on the right side of the equation det _A_ becomes a number and can be pulled outside of the second determinant which becomes the determinant of 1, which equals 1, correct? So, the right side of the equation become (det _A_)^n, which then has the det( _A_) from the left side of the equation divided into to complete the proof, correct?

Comment: Yes --- write it up and post it as an answer. Only be sure to deal with the special case when $\det A=0$ and you can't divide by $\det A$.

Comment: I have changed the question title. In particular, as the word 'adjoint' has multiple meanings, I replace it by 'adjugate' to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*A*(adj *A*) = |*A*|(I)

|*A*(adj *A*)| = |(|*A*| I)|

|*A*| |adj *A*| = $|A|^n  * |I|$

|*A*| |adj *A*| = $|A|^n $

**case 1**: if  |*A*|$\neq0$

Then we get ,|adj *A*| = $|A|^{n-1}  $

**case 2**: if  |*A*|$=0$

Then,|adj *A*|$=0$

And, we again get |adj *A*| = $|A|^{n-1}  $

Comment: Wait a minute --- what does $||A||$ mean? Does it mean $\det(\det A)$? But $\det A$ is a number, not a matrix, so what does $\det(\det A)$ mean, and why is it $(\det A)^n$? And how do you go from the next-to-last line to the last line? Did you divide by $\det A$? What if $\det A=0$? And why didn't you let OP write it out? We were so close....

Comment: OK, you took care of the $\det A=0$ problem --- but I had some other questions....

Comment: Yeah,$||A||$ means $ det(detA)$. it is equal to $(detA)^n$.OP already explained it in his comment

Comment: Sorry, but $\det(\det A)=(\det A)^n$ is nonsense. What's true is $\det((\det A)I)=(\det A)^n\det I=(\det A)^n$. We take determinants of matrices, not of numbers.

Comment: How can you know that if |A| =0 then |adj(A)| =0?

Comment: @user124697: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881654/the-determinant-of-adjugate-matrix

Comment: @Gerry Myerson. I agree, but technically the number 1 is a 1x1 Identity Matrix. So, you could still take the det(det(A)) which is just det(A)^1 which is det(A).

Answer (score 7):

We have the relation
$$A \operatorname{adj}(A)=\det(A)I $$
Now take determinant on both the sides we get,
$$\det(A)\det(\operatorname{adj}(A))=\det(\det(A)I) \tag1$$
use the relation that, for a matrix $A$ that is $n \times n$,

$$\det(kA)=k^n (\det(A))$$
where k is a numerical constant. Hence we have

$$\det(\det(A)I)=\det(A)^n \det (I)=\det(A)^n \tag2$$
and from equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows that
$$\det(A)\det(\operatorname{adj}(A))=\det(A)^n ,$$
which implies
$$\det(\operatorname{adj}(A)) = \det(A)^{n-1} .$$

Comment: This is very difficult to read. MathJax would certainly help as well as some other formatting. Regards

Comment: This works in case where $A$ is invertible. (Since in this case we have, $det(A)≠0$)

Answer (score 2):

We know that $A\cdot adj(A) = detA\cdot I$

Now, this implies $$\det(A\cdot adjA) = \det(\det A\cdot I)$$

The matrix on the right is a diagonal matrix with each diagonal entry equal to $detA$

Thus, its determinant will simply be the product of the diagonal entries,
$(\det A)^n$

Also, using the multiplicity of determinant function, we get $\det(A\cdot adjA) = \det A\cdot \det(adjA)$

**Case $1$:** $\det A \neq 0$

This directly gives us $\det(adjA) = (detA)^{n-1}$

**Case $2$:** $\det A = 0$

**Case $2.1$ :** $A = 0$

This simply means that $adjA = 0$ thus satisfying the result obtained in case 1.

**Case $2.2$ :** $A\neq 0$

This means that $adjA$ isn't invertible. If it would have been, then right multiplication with $(adjA)^{-1}$ would have given $A = 0$, Thus a contradiction.

Now, as $adjA$ isn't invertible, this implies $det(adjA) = 0$ , thus completing the proof.

Answer (score 0):

[Case I] det (Adj(A))=0

[Case II] det (Adj(A)) = nonzero, so Adj(A) is invertible.

Let (Adj(A))^{-1} =B. From  A Adj(A)=det(A)I,  A Adj(A) B=  det(A)I B.

So A = B det(A)I.

Suppose that det(A)=0.  Then A = 0. So Adj A =0 implies det (Adj A)=0, a contradiction.

Therefore det (A) = nonzero. Now we have det (Adj(A))=det (A)^{n-1}.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  You chose to respond to a Question that is three years old, and you've given no indication what you think is new information, relative to older Answers, in your post.  Although distinguishing the cases $\det(Adj(A))= 0$ and $\det(Adj(A))\neq 0$ may be a useful tactic, there are some details you omitted in the proof or calculation.  See this [introduction to posting mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).