# Inverse of the adjugate operation

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry

In projective geometry, the map between a primal and dual quadric is the adjugate: $adj(Q) = Q^*$. The map from dual to primal is then the inverse adjugate, $Q = adj^{-1}(Q^*)$, as in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7919240).

How is this calculated? I know the adjugate is the inverse multiplied by the determinant, but I don't see how to invert this operation.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some math with determinants, it looks like $adj^{-1}(A) = A^{-1} * |A|^{\frac{1}{1 - dim(A)}}$ (based on [The determinant of adjugate matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516127/the-determinant-of-adjugate-matrix?rq=1)).